# Custom path Swagger resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and swagger-springmvc:1.0.2. I'm setting the base path of my application to "/". And Swagger is loading under

http://localhost:9000/swagger/index.html

I need to change that, but keeping the root of my application as "/". I need to write a rule, something like:

- If somebody hits http://localhost:9000/SOMETHING/swagger/index.html, then open http://localhost:9000/swagger/index.html.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URI template pattern (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates), even to the extent of using regular expressions depending on how specific you need to be.